# Illustrator CS4: SVG Export error "Transforms are Expanded"?

Tags: export, adobe-illustrator, svg

I get the following error when trying to save my image to SVG (via "Save Copy As"):

```
Transforms are expanded.
```

When I try to load the SVG in another program, all I get is a blank canvas. I ultimately want the path data to feed into RaphaelJS, but the path data that I got by clicking on the `Show Code` button during the SVG export also yields a blank canvas with RaphaelJS (and I've verified that RaphaelJS is loaded, and it is rendering properly).

I'm convinced that this export error in Illustrator is the problem, but I can't figure out how to make it go away and export my SVG graphic properly.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that Illustrator was translating my whole image by about 500 pixels or so downwards and to the left, for some reason. So, loading the exported image **looked** like a blank canvas, but expanding the work area (when re-opening in Illustrator) revealed my whole image just "off the screen". I selected and moved it back, then re-saved the SVG (saved, not exported), and it works fine now.

Kinda five extra steps, but hey, at least it works. Don't know why Illustrator felt the need to translate the position of my entire image...

Comment: It's always best to use the artboard tool to set the origin to 0 0 (and I prefer whole pixel artboards sizes but perhaps that's just OCD ;-)

Answer (score 25):

I just randomly tried this and it worked! I'm able to save the SVG without getting the "Transforms are expanded." error message. I can't explain why it works, but it does.

Try the following:

Object > Select all > Flatten transparency (high res) > Save!

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Comment: This worked great for me. Fixed all the SVGs I had different kinds of problems with.

Comment: Still works. Illustrator CC 2015, osx 10.10. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me in Illustrator CC2017 Mac OS Sierra. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's somehow related to effects on borders, at least I encounter it most of the time together with borders. Identify which border it is, select it in the *Layers*, and go to *Object* → *Path* → *Outline Stroke*. This should do the trick when saving to SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this old question cuz it was first in google search and wasn't helpful at all. Hopefully my answer will help other people to not waste their time in continued search of solution.

This error appears while saving SVG file because as said in the error message, literally your transforms are expanded. You need to fix transforms of your objects, to do that, click on Selection Tool(V) then drag and select all the objects on the canvas, then go to Object > Expand > click Ok on the opened window, Done. Your transforms are now fixed.

Go to File > Save As > and save SVG. In the opened window click "More Options" and enter number 3 in the "Decimal Places"(default is 1) - to avoid shapes deformations in the saved file.

Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Your illustration is probably either too complicated to be represented as an SVG document or too complicated for Adobe's SVG exporter to handle. Adobe has more or less abandoned SVG, so your best bet is probably going to be to look to another vendor.

Comment: rubbish I'm afraid. I came here because of a similar problem with 7 lines of SVG code. Illustrator is my tool of choice for designing and editing vector graphics and there's nothing wrong with its SVG code, as long as you are prepared to treat it as that, code.

Comment: SVG is the future of web graphics and is here to stay. There is no doubt about that. The clarity and control you have is unprecedented.